# Enforce DOMContentLoaded event on Window before jQuery Document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, document-ready, domcontentloaded

Say I have the following two script tags somewhere on my page:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
        function()
        {
            console.log("DOM loaded");
        }
    );
</script>
...
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            console.log("Document ready");
        }
    );
</script>
```

Is there any easy way to enforce that the DOMContentLoaded event fires before `$().ready`?

This is a simplified example of my actual problem. The real problem I'm facing is that the DOMContentLoaded event is registered in a third-party library that I am including at the bottom of my page's body, and I have far too many `$().ready` calls to change them all quickly. I could, in theory, change `window.addEventListener` to `document.addEventListener` without creating any problems, but because I'm including jQuery in my page's head, all `$().ready` calls still fire before `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"...)`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534726/non-jquery-ready-alternative-that-executes-before-jquerys-ready-unlike-d), and I can't reasonably move the include location of jQuery or this third-party library. I would also like to avoid making changes to the third-party library if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.holdReady()`

```
<script>
    $.holdReady(true);
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      console.log("DOM loaded");
      $.holdReady(false);
    });
</script>
...
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("Document ready");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If jQuery might not be included, would it be sufficient to surround both `holdReady` calls in `if (typeof $() != 'undefined')`?

Comment: @JimmyP _"If jQuery might not be included"_ Not sure what you mean? Is not premise of Question `.ready()` handler being called before `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That was the original question, but now I am curious; if one of my pages includes this third-party library that registers the `DOMContentLoaded` event while jQuery isn't present on the page, it's going to throw an undefined error.

Comment: `$` could be defined as a function or value other than `jQuery()`, you can check `window.jQuery`